# lists in vb.net, struggling with structure

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm having a bit of trouble with a list in vb.net.

Basically what I am trying to do is send an email and the user can select from 4 options to send a carbon copy to. I started out with a series of if statements checking to see if a checkbox was checked and if it was then it added it to CC, but that seems to only ever add one. So I created ccList, the idea is it creates a list of strings and adds that to cc instead. I'm not sure if it will work but if I add a break in the second, third or fourth if, it doesn't fall into it and only ever passes through the first (if every check box is true). If I only check one then it falls into that one correctly.

```
 If FSEmailAddress <> "" Then
        Dim OutlookMessage As outlook.MailItem
        Dim AppOutlook As New outlook.Application
        Dim ccList As List(Of String) = Nothing
        Try

OutlookMessage = AppOutlook.CreateItem(outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
                Dim Recipents As outlook.Recipients = OutlookMessage.Recipients
            Recipents.Add(FSEmailAddress)

            If email1.Checked = True Then
                ccList.Add("email1@some.email.com")
            End If

            If email2.Checked = True Then
                ccList.Add("email2@some.email.com; ")
            End If

            If email3.Checked = True Then
                ccList.Add("email3@some.email.com; ")
            End If

            If email4.Checked = True Then
                ccList.Add("email4@some.email.com; ")
            End If

            OutlookMessage.CC = ccList.ToString

            OutlookMessage.Subject = responseVIN.Text & " was sent back to you by " & GetUserName()
            'link = archive_dir & responseVIN.Text
            OutlookMessage.Body = responseVIN.Text & " was returned To you" & vbCrLf & "Navigate To the following location To view the comments In the ReadMe file:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & archive_dir & responseVIN.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & resAdvice.Text
            OutlookMessage.BodyFormat = outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
            OutlookMessage.Send()
```

Comment: `So I created ccList...` actually you did not create anything - that code just declares an object variable.  `Dim ccList and New List(Of String)` does both.  No idea of the rest of your problem - its a debugging issue.

Comment: @Plutonix well he created `Nothing` :D I guess the try catch block will save from actaully seeing an error, after he adds a string to a null object ;)

Comment: I don't think ccList.ToString does what you think it does. You might have to look at doing a Join. If you add email 1 and 2, you'll be missing a ; between them. I think you have a few little think going wrong here. I would suggest you do one small thing at a time and make sure it works well before doing something else.

Comment: @Plutonix - Thanks, the key word "New" actually fixed the problem! It's always obvious when somebody else points it out...

Comment: @the_lotus I think you might be right. I'm just playing with it but I think my next problem will be what you highlighted!

Comment: Just a minor thing to note here: `If email1.Checked = True Then` (for each email checkbox reference) can probably be simplified to just `If email1.Checked Then`. The boolean comparison with `True` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody interested:

Here is the solution to both of the problems I was having:

```
        Dim FSEmailAddress As String = ""
    Dim link As String = ""
    Dim ccJoin As String = ""

    If FSEngineerName = "Email 1" Then
        FSEmailAddress = "email1@some.email.com"
    ElseIf FSEngineerName = "Email 2" Then
        FSEmailAddress = "email2@some.email.com"
    ElseIf FSEngineerName = "Email 3" Then
        FSEmailAddress = "email3@some.email.com"
    ElseIf FSEngineerName = "Email 4" Then
        FSEmailAddress = "email4@some.email.com"
    End If

    If FSEmailAddress <> "" Then
        Dim OutlookMessage As outlook.MailItem
        Dim AppOutlook As New outlook.Application
        Dim ccList As New List(Of String)
        Try

            OutlookMessage = AppOutlook.CreateItem(outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
            Dim Recipents As outlook.Recipients = OutlookMessage.Recipients

            Recipents.Add(FSEmailAddress)

        If email1.Checked Then
            ccList.Add("email1@some.email.com")
        End If

        If email2.Checked Then
            ccList.Add("email2@some.email.com; ")
        End If

        If email3.Checked Then
            ccList.Add("email3@some.email.com; ")
        End If

        If email4.Checked Then
            ccList.Add("email4@some.email.com; ")
        End If

            ccJoin = String.Join("; ", ccList.ToArray())

            OutlookMessage.CC = ccJoin

            OutlookMessage.Subject = responseVIN.Text & " was sent back to you by " & GetUserName()
            OutlookMessage.Body = responseVIN.Text & " was returned To you" & vbCrLf & "Navigate To the following location To view the comments In the ReadMe file:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & archive_dir & responseVIN.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & resAdvice.Text
            OutlookMessage.BodyFormat = outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
            OutlookMessage.Send()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Mail could Not be sent")
        Finally
            OutlookMessage = Nothing
            AppOutlook = Nothing
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: You probably would have found out the answer if you didn't use such a large try catch block. Now the full logic is in the block while it should suffice to at most capture the error sending the email. Also if you choose to capture exceptions, you should always analyse that you handle them properly